# Different behaviour between 'returning a promise' and 'resolving with promise' inside a `new`-generated promise

Tags: javascript, promise

It's not much I discovered Javascript `Promise`.
However I found out a behaviour I couldn't understand concerning the nesting of (new or returned) `Promise` inside `Promises`

That's the background (`extPromiseX` is a third-party function returning `Promise`):

#### Case 1:

```
function myAction(param) {
    return extPromise1(sql).then((result) => {
        [...]
        return extPromise2(sql2).then((result) => {
            [...]
            return extPromise3(sql3);
        })
   });
}

// Main Process
myAction(...)
.then(() => { 
    console.log('Process Terminated');
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Exit with error', error);
});
```

Now, as expected, I got from the console, in

```
1) extPromise1 completed
2) extPromise2 completed
3) extPromise3 completed
4) Process Terminated
```

#### Case 2:

```
function myAction(param) {
    return new Promise(function() {
        if (itsAllOkWithInputs) {
            // Some sync code here
            return extPromise1(sql).then((result) => {
                [...]
                return extPromise2(sql2).then((result) => {
                    [...]
                    return extPromise3(sql3);
                })
            })
        } else {
            throw 'Something went wrong';
        }
    });
}

// Main process
myAction(...)
.then(() => {
    console.log('Process Terminated');
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('3) --> Exit with error', error);
})
```

In this second case `extPromise`s are executed but the very first `Promise` remains pending (confirmed by debug). So the console shows:

```
1) extPromise1 completed
2) extPromise2 completed
3) extPromise3 completed
```

I empirically realized that I had to change `myAction` function as follow for the code to work:

```
function myAction(param) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       if (itsAllOkWithInputs) {
           // Some sync code here
           let ep = extPromise1(sql).then(...);
           resolve(ep);
       } else {
           throw 'Something went wrong';
       }
   });
}
```

My question:
I thought returning a promise inside another *parental* one would make
the parent resolving with the results of the child. This is the case
inside the `then` code block applied to the external promises.  Why
this is not valid for the `new Promise` case?

Comment: case 2: returning in a promise constructor makes no sense .. you need to resolve or reject in a promise constructor, however, since the code in the constructor already has a promise, then don't use the promise constructor anti-pattern

Comment: @JaromandaX: `myAction` has to return a `Promise`, but, before calling the external one, I have to manage checks upon inputs. This was the reason why I adopted a promise constructor. Any different solution?

Comment: yes, promise chaining, you know ... `.then(....).then(....)` etc

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504663/why-does-a-promise-return-an-object-promise-even-if-i-put-return-explicitly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324110/why-does-the-promise-constructor-require-a-function-that-calls-resolve-when-complete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780377/return-value-from-a-promise-constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `.then` is meant to *chain* promises. You can return a Promise from inside the then callback, and then itself will return a new Promise.

The Promise constructor is supposed to construct a Promise from an underlying callback. If you return a Promise from inside a Promise constructor, you are doing something wrong conceptually. And that's why it does not work.

```
 function myAction(param) {
   if (itsAllOkWithInputs) {
       return extPromise1(sql).then(...);           
   } else {
       return Promise.reject('Something went wrong');
   }
 }

 // OR
async function myAction(param) {
   if (itsAllOkWithInputs) {
       await extPromise1(sql);     
   } else {
       throw 'Something went wrong';
   }
 }
```

Comment: That explains  exactly my doubt. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> new Promise(function() {
> ```

You are not using neither `resolve` nor `reject` arguments (you actually even haven't declared them), so the promise will never get resolved or rejected. All other stuff is irrelevant.

If your function returns promise, you have to simply call it and return a result. If you don't know whether the function return promise or just a value, you can wrap it's call into `Promise.resolve`, but not in `new Promise`.